# Quarkus demo project fails to launch

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I am trying to run Quarkus demo project from [here](https://code.quarkus.io/). But when I run the command `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev`, it fails to run with the following errors

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain
```

I mention, that I've tried the possible solution presented in this issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1707, but none of them worked.

The complete stack trace can be found here
https://gist.github.com/cosminpopescu14/ec17967d21b3e64cb7393ac776c39a9e

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just tried to create an empty project and it works. Which JVM do you use? We support 8 and 11.

Comment: Seems the test has passed :)

Comment: I've switched to java 11 and now it's working. Thank you for your answer.